# C compiler cannot create executables when brew install

Tags: homebrew

Saw below error when running `brew install hub` and `brew install gh`

```
configure: error: in `/tmp/pkg-config-20220914-13522-pwtaq4/pkg-config-0.29.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
```

When I look at `config.log`, I found below errors:

```
configure:3434: gcc-7 -V >&5
gcc-7: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
configure:3445: $? = 1
configure:3434: gcc-7 -qversion >&5
gcc-7: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
```

I think it's because we should use `-v` instead `-V` or `-qversion`, but how can I change that?

Comment: This is not a real error, it's just an option check by configure. The real error should be in the end of the log - the last one before the definitions are start being listed.